# When I turn my steering wheel when my car is parked and on the car almost cuts off?

Tags: honda, accord, steering-wheel

I have a 2001 Honda Accord lx 4 cylinder, just like the question says when I turn the steering wheel while it is parked the car almost cuts off?

Comment: How's your power steering fluid reservoir look? Full? Red? How's it smell?

Comment: I would bet there is a problem with your steering rack or possibly the power steering pump, but that would be a SWAG on my part.

Answer (score 3):

My subaru does this in winter if i turn the steering wheel before warming the car up.

As above, it could be problem with your power steering pump, or fluid.  It might also be your car is idling too low.

Turn your wheel, and the pump kicks in, using the engine + pulley to power it.  You're putting a load on the engine when all it wants to do is idle... Normally your car should pick up the revs to compensate for this... but if that isn't happening.. the root cause could be many other things.  e.g. Mass Airflow Sensor, ECU, etc.

You might be able to try isolating the problem by turning the car on, in park; then turn the air con on (if you have it).  It should put a load on the engine similar to the power steering pump.  If your car sounds like stalling (cutting off) then chances are the problem isn't your power steering pump, rather something that controls the idle speed of the car.

Answer (score 1):

May have two problems first I would check power steering pressure switch then would make sure idle air control valve is working properly